# What is the best way to have a distortion field on a bitmap?

Tags: java, android, opencv, image-processing, opengl-es

I'm looking to implement image distortions on specific places (such as the eyes of a face). Tools like this are used in many applications that use facial filters like Snapchat.

[Tom hardy distorted face](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jUOY4.jpg)

I've already done some research, I've found several leads but I can't figure out what the optimal is, if it works and especially if there's no better way to do this kind of distortion. I've seen that opencv has a remap function, but a lot of people seem to say that the function takes time to execute. I saw that you could do this with opengl but I didn't really find any concrete examples and I'm afraid to start learning opengl for nothing.

Just for information, I am already able to get the necessary information on the faces, I just need a lead to get started in the distortion / deformation of the face.

Comment: Best in what way ?

Comment: In the best way so that the distortion runs quickly on smartphones, whether the application is on a static image or on the camera dynamically.

Comment: OpenGL is a good option then, as it uses the hardware acceleration of graphics embedded in the processor.

Comment: Okay, thank you very much. Do you have any examples to apply this kind of modification with opengl es?

Comment: Absolutely not.